# Improve SQL Query Runtime

Tags: mysql, sql, runtime

New to SQL. I am trying to get some week-over-week trends to compare various metric points. This is what I have so far. The runtime is bad because it goes through the entire table 4 times and this is only for the past 4 weeks. Is there any way to improve this process and also get metrics for all the past weeks (not just the last 4) ?

Edit: This is MySQL.

Sample Data:

| Timestamp | Metric Hits | Metric Total | Metric Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-20 06:50:01.332000 | 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-08-31 08:49:59.086000 | 2 | 3 | 0.6666 |
| 2022-08-09 04:50:12.430000 | 1 | 2 | 0.5 |

```
SELECT
    sum(metric_hits) as metric_hits_sum,
    sum(metric_total) as metrics_total_sum,
    avg(metric_value) as metric_value_avg
from metric_events
where timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date) and timestamp < DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date)
UNION
SELECT
    sum(metric_hits) as metric_hits_sum,
    sum(metric_total) as metrics_total_sum,
    avg(metric_value) as metric_value_avg
from metric_events
where timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -14-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date) and timestamp < DATEADD(DAY, -7-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date)
UNION
SELECT
    sum(metric_hits) as metric_hits_sum,
    sum(metric_total) as metrics_total_sum,
    avg(metric_value) as metric_value_avg
from metric_events
where timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -21-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date) and timestamp < DATEADD(DAY, -14-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date)
UNION
SELECT
    sum(metric_hits) as metric_hits_sum,
    sum(metric_total) as metrics_total_sum,
    avg(metric_value) as metric_value_avg
from metric_events
where timestamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -28-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date) and timestamp < DATEADD(DAY, -21-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS?  That is critical since you are dealing with date calculations.  Also, please provide sample data.

Comment: Since you're aggregating, more sample input data would be helpful.  It would also be good to include your desired output based on that input.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you closer.  I'll leave you to add more features (like week begin and end dates)

```
select floor((daysold - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date)) / 7) as weeksold
, sum(metric_hits) as metric_hits_sum
, sum(metric_total) as metrics_total_sum
, avg(metric_value) as metric_value_avg
from (
  SELECT datediff(day, [timestamp], GETDATE()::date) as daysold
  , metric_hits
  , metric_total
  , metric_value
  from metric_events
  where [timestamp] < DATEADD(DAY, -DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date), GETDATE()::date)
) q
group by floor((daysold - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()::date)) / 7)
order by 1
```